# Нужна помощь в составлении регулярки на PHP

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

В HTML тексте имеется запись:

> redirect('Some value','Some value 2');

Нужно получить 'Some value' и 'Some value 2' в две переменные. Удалось получить только строку в виде `'Some value','Some value 2'`. Заранее спасибо за помощь.

Comment: _'Some value','Some value 2'_ Это точно строка, а не массив из двух элементов?

Comment: @HakuKimura, да, дебаг через var_dump

Comment: `"/\'[^.]\'/"` - таким паттерном удалось вернуть только `','`..

Comment: Попробуйте `/\'[\w\s]+\'/iu`.

Comment: @HakuKimura да, уже возвращает по-отдельности, можно как-то сделать возврат без `'`? Правда я убрал их через `preg_replace`, но вдруг можно это сделать ещё при отборе.

Comment: `/redirect\(\s*'([^,]+)'\s*,\s*'([^,]+)'\s*\)/i` https://regex101.com/r/IRTCdZ/2

Comment: Решили данную задачу?

Answer (score 1):

Вот как вы получили строку вида `'Some value','Some value 2'` - она хранится в переменной, ниже распишу что к чему:

```
<?php

    // Получение в переменную $string = "'Some value','Some value 2'"

    $string = str_replace("'", "", $string);  // Учитывая что вы получили строку с кавычками ''
    $values = explode(',', $string);
```

Comment: Тоже неплохой вариант

Comment: У вас работает?

Answer (score 0):

если строка именно такая и точно есть два значения в одинарных кавычках, то есть если оно из них пустое, то должно быть '', то вот регулярка, которая просто выдает массив значений заключенных к одинарные кавычки

```
<?php
$string = "redirect('Some value','Some value 2');";
$pattern = '/\'.*?\'/';
preg_match_all($pattern, $string, $arr);


//результаты
echo $arr[0][0] . "\n";
echo $arr[0][1];

//выводит
// 'Some value'
// 'Some value 2'
```

Answer (score 0):

Если сделать допущение, что внутри кавычек нет других кавычек, то самый простой вариант:

```
preg_match(
    "/redirect\('(?<val1>.*?)','(?<val2>.*?)'\);/",
    "redirect('Some value','Some value 2');",
    $matches
);
var_dump($matches['val1']);
var_dump($matches['val2']);
```

В результате:

```
string(10) "Some value"
string(12) "Some value 2"
```

Answer (score -3):

Можно дальше и не регулярным выражением:

```
$string = my_get_string_from_incoming_html("... redirect('Some value','Some value 2'); ...");
$strings = explode(",", $string);
```

Comment: Метка стоит `php`, у вас ответ не соответствует синтаксису `php`. Что за метод такой `get_string`?

Comment: Поправил для понятливости

Comment: А, вы и так поняли что имелось в виду и, перефразировав, оформили как ответ :)

Comment: Вы меня простите, но у вас даже синтаксис не php.

Comment: Вы не правильно ответили, по нескольким причинам, как минимум трем. Что мне запрещает написать развернутый и правильный ответ?

Comment: уговорили, добавил `;` ))

Comment: Не является ответом, т.к. на вопросе метка php, а в ответе синтаксис не php-шный.

Comment: а, точно, тут же ещё $ перед именами.